# Secure communication between Oracle client and server

Tags: security, oracle

As per project requirement i need to to secure communication between Oracle server and client. I have oracle version 11g. What are the configuration steps i need to follow in the client and server side for attaining secure communication

What if i want to do this secure communication using Programming. What is the syntax i need to follow?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Oracle Advanced Security](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14268/toc.htm). If you don't have the Enterprise Edition, then you could look at a VPN solution.

I'm not sure what you mean by "secure the communication using Programming".

Comment: It is an extra cost option.
"Oracle Advanced Security provides transparent data encryption of data stored in the database, the encryption of disk-based backups of the database, and also network encryption for data traveling across the network between the database and client or mid-tier applications."
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/license.102/b14199/options.htm#CIHFDJDG

Answer (score 0):

stunnel is the way to go, if you dont have any other option.